# Why is WalnutDSA specified for COSE?

Tags: cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, file-format

WalnutDSA was a 1st-round entrant in the NIST Post-Quantum Cryptography project. It had a significant cryptanalytic break close to almost breaking the security of the cryptosystem, only survived due to the break cannot fit a bogous signature into the length field of the encoded signature.

Why was such (almost) broken crypto system specified for use with [COSE](https://www.iana.org/assignments/cose/cose.xhtml#key-type)? Who was pushing for it?